# Hiring range/wage vs. Salary/wage range

Tags: job-search, salary, hiring, canada

I'm considering applying for a position which just posted in my field of work (within government). The position itself is right up my alley; however, what caught my eye in the job posting is that they have two different salary/wage ranges posted and I'm not entirely certain what that means:

Hiring range/wage $:    XX - XX
Salary/wage range $:    XX - XX

The Salary/wage range is higher than the Hiring range/wage, which might imply that the hiring range is what range they would offer the successful applicant. Upon passing probation, you would move to the Salary/wage range. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Does the Hiring range fit inside the salary range or is there an overlap? It might help to use example numbers in the question or at least don't use the the same letter for all the numbers.

Comment: Your country, please?

Comment: I'm in Ontario, Canada. The Hiring range does fit within the salary range. E.g.,
Hiring range $5 - $10
Salary range $7 - $12

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a "ask the recruiter" case.

I would assume at the very least that you are hired w/in the hiring range, and that your eventual potential wages are the salary range.  But I suspect that how that translates is very job/group specific and should be part of what you talk through with the recruiter as you go through the application process.

Comment: Yes. exactly, ask. And, usually in government these wage ranges come down from on high, from some kind of regulations. So, you won't cause trouble or give offense by asking. It's a fact of the job, just like the location of the office or the number of vacation days.

Answer (score 0):

If I saw that the hiring range was completely inside the salary range such as:

```
Hiring range:  --7-9---
Salary Range:  5------12
```

Then I would understand it as for this specific job they will start you in the range of 7 to 9 depending on the new hire's experience level. But positions in the organization with that job title can be paid a rate of 5 to 12. That means that you know the ceiling for that job title. Which means that annual increases can get you closer to the ceiling, but you will need a promotion to another title to get above the ceiling.

The other thing it tells me is that if a person already with the employer looking for a transfer, they can determine if they will see a change in pay if they make the transfer.

If the salary range is as stated in the comment:

> Hiring range $5 - $10 Salary range $7 - $12

That is confusing. It almost seems like they are suggesting two different titles depending on the level of experience. If you have zero experience you will be paid as a low-level-title in the range of $5 to $7, but if you have more experience you will be a mid-level-title in the range of $7 to $10.

In this case I would ask the hiring manger/recruiter, or similar POC. This is important to do if the rate of pay will be the deciding factor, and you aren't interested if you will only be considered for the low end of the range.